# Где в Laravel лучше хранить изначальные переменные?

Tags: php, laravel

Сейчас перевожу небольшой самописный движок на Laravel и не могу понять, где лучше всего инициализировать переменные, которые я потом буду использовать повсеместно?

Например, у меня есть массив из 23 городов, который никогда не меняется и жестко прописан в коде. Куда его правильно разместить, чтобы он был доступен отовсюду?

Comment: Возможно, стоит рассмотреть этот вариант https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration

Comment: В /config/app.php ?

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем правильно хранить такие данные в конфигурации. И дико не удобно. В конфигурации хранятся значения зависящие от среды, в которой выполняется приложение.
Для ваших целей лучше использовать хелперы (helpers). Например, создать класс со статическим методом:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class CityHelper
{
    public static function citiesList()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Вызываете где угодно `CityHelper::citiesList()`

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решил создать свой файлик конфигурации

```
/config/sitename.php
```

Разместил в нем все данные и обращаюсь к ним по

```
config('sitename.varname')
```

Все суперудобно.

Спасибо [NaClnik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/347001/naclnik) за подсказку.

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь